# How to fix faultcode:'sf:MALFORMED_QUERY, faultString:'MALFORMED_QUERY'?

Tags: soql, javascript

I have Onclick javascript button to perform multiple actions on the records displayed on a list view.

JS CODE:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/38.0/apex.js")} 

 if("{!User.Profile}" == "Custom user" || "{!User.Profile}" == "System 
    Administrator"){  
 var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.sm1e__smWork_Order__c)}; 
 var RecordIds = ''; 
 if(records[0] == null){ 
 alert("Please select a record"); 
 }else{ 
 for(var n = 0; n < records.length; n++){ 
 if(RecordIds == '') 
 RecordIds = '\'' + records[n] + '\''; 
 else 
 RecordIds = RecordIds+ ", " + '\'' + records[n] + '\''; 
 } 
 //alert('RecordIds: '+RecordIds); 
try{ 
var caseRecords = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, RecordType.Name, 
sm1e__Assigned_To__c, sm1e__Status__c FROM sm1e__smWork_Order__c Where Id 
IN ("+RecordIds+")"); 

var workOrderRecords = caseRecords.getArray("records"); 
//alert('records: '+workOrderRecords); 
for(i = 0; i < caseRecords.getArray("records").length; i++){ 
caseRecords.getArray("records")[i].sm1e__Assigned_To__c = "{!User.Id}"; 
caseRecords.getArray("records")[i].sm1e__Status__c = "Approved"; 
caseRecords.getArray("records")[i].RecordType.Name = "Work_Order"; 
} 
sforce.connection.update(caseRecords.getArray("records")); 
window.top.location.reload(); 
}catch(e){ 
alert("An Error has Occurred. Error: " + e); 
} 
} 
}else{ 
alert("You do not have necessary permissions. Please contact your system 
adminstrator"); 
}
```

When i try to access this button from the list view, I'm getting "faultcode:'sf:MALFORMED_QUERY, faultString:'MALFORMED_QUERY'" error.

I assume i'm making some mistake with the I wrtote Record type in the SOQL Query. But Unable to figure it out.

How should I handle this exception?

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried to correct this? (this is a very common mistake, you should be able to correct by yourself with a little effort)

Comment: Your code does not require a query to begin with. Perhaps you should start from the beginning and try and make an update.